# Switch OpenTok Publisher to specific video device

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

When wishing to change the audio input device (i.e. microphone) of an OpenTok `Publisher` object, you can use:

`Publisher.setAudioSource(<id_of_microphone_device_here>)`

...in order to specify which microphone you'd like to switch to.

---

However, if you want to change the **video source** (i.e. camera), the only option [that I could find] is to use:

`Publisher.cycleVideo()`

...which returns (via a promise) the ID of the media device / webcam that you've switched to by 'cycling' up a step.

**Is there a method that I can use to specifically switch to a video device ID of my choosing, without having to:**

a. Re-initialize my `Publisher` object?

-or-

b. Cycle through my video devices until I find the one I want?

---

I'm asking because, let's for argument's sake, assume that a user has 10 camera inputs — some of which they don't wish to 'cycle' through live on-stream in order to get to the one they want.

Is it possible to target a video device's ID just like we can for an audio device?

Something I tried to do in order to 'hack' this to work was to first disable the video output of a publisher (`Publisher.publishVideo(false)`), cycle through to find the one I want, and then 're-enable' the video output. However, disabling a publisher's video output seems to have the unfortunate consequence of not being able to cycle through its video devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

Unlike `setAudioSource`, there is no comparative method for video.

One alternative would be to publish the video to a canvas and use that as the source for the publisher. You can learn more about doing so at https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/publish-stream/js/#canvas.

Then utilize `MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` to identify your device and write its output to the canvas. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices

Comment: Using the canvas is not something I thought to do! That is a good workaround for now — thanks for your help :)

Comment: 2022 update, there is now a `Publisher.setVideoSource` method:
https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#setVideoSource